# How to draw different shapes using pencil on group container and resize and rotate it in flex4?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.6

All operations like moving,rotating,resizing drawn shape can be performed.I'm using as3 and flex4.6.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have to use object handles library for moving,rotating, re sizing shapes ..
you can download this library from the below links.

https://github.com/marc-hughes/ObjectHandles

http://www.objecthandles.com/

Comment: thanks.Will it work for the diagram drawn by pencil on the group container.if work then how?

Comment: And how should i use this library.